# How can I join/fuse/weld the corners using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So, I've added a tetrahedron using the Math Function>Regular Solids Mesh option. Then using some simple Geometry Nodes I made the wrieframe into tubes. Now I'd like to connect and seal the ends together so that the whole thing is manifold and without overlapping geometry. Is there a way to do this in Geometry Nodes? Or is there a better method? I thought of trying to do it manually but that seems tedious and I figured there must be a better way.

[image]

Here is the example .blend file

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is no in-house vanilla way to do this in geonodes. I haven't seen anyone implement this. Remesh seems like the most obvious workaround, and last time I tried, the skin modifier would crash Blender when tried on top of geonodes. Working under some limit, e.g. there's only 3 joined lines, the algorithm maybe wouldn't be all that hard, but I've approached the problem a few times without such constraints and the issues quickly pile up…

Comment: Thanks for the ingo @MarkusvonBroady, the simple tetrahedron is just practice. I intend to work on some more complex shapes later after I got the hang of the method. I'll keep toying with it and see what workaround I can figure out.